# Python list - removing some list entries

Tags: python, list

I have a directory that stores multiple configuration files, with the same naming logic. First comes the date of the backup and then the device name. I would like to write a script that would go through all the files in the directory and keep just the oldest occurence of the backup files.

Example directory content prior to script running:

```
02-10-2023__Device1.tar
03-10-2023__Device2.tar
01-11-2023__Device1.tar
03-11-2023__Device2.tar
04-11-2023__Device1.tar
06-11-2023__Device2.tar
11-11-2023__Device2.tar
...
```

Avaited result after the running of the script:

```
02-10-2023__Device1.tar
03-10-2023__Device2.tar
01-11-2023__Device1.tar
03-11-2023__Device2.tar
```

The script should not touch the older (october) backups and keep just the "oldest" november backups. In the example above there are just two devices in my case there are 100+ different devices.

I tried to do it using `os.listdir` to populate a list of directory contents. I used the datetime to get the current month/year data. I then tried to go through the list using a for loop and populate a new list where I would only store the file names that should be erased using `os.remove`. I get stuck at the step where I try to count the accourances of the file name ending in a certian way.

Am I on the right track or is there a simpler way?

Code up to this point:

```
import os, datetime

today=datetime.date.today()
month=today.month
year=today.year
date=str(str(month) + "-" + str(year))


files=os.listdir()

erase=[]


for file in files:
    if ????? and str(file[3:10]) == date:
        erase.append(file)
        os.remove(erase)
```

I'm just not sure how I could add the first if statement that would only add files where there is a an existing file allready. I did try to play with "files.count(file[3:]) > 1", but that does not work.

Comment: How are you stuck exactly? Show us your code. See [mre]. See also [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: @Demions Can you provide an example of the expected result? I'm having trouble understanding at which step you are getting stuck.

Comment: Sorry I added the code to the original post.

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense. You say "The script should not touch the older (october) backups and keep just the "oldest" november backups." If you're just going to keep the two oldest November backups, how can you do that without removing the October backups? Also, when you say "November", I assume you mean current month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider breaking down your script into smaller easier to reason about functions:

```
import datetime
import os
import subprocess
from collections import defaultdict


def get_device_name(filename: str) -> str:
  """Extracts the device name from the filename.

  Args:
    filename: The filename to extract the device name from.

  Returns:
    str: The extracted device name.
  """
  return filename.split("__")[1]


def group_files_by_device(files: list[str]) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
  """Groups files by device name.

  Args:
    files: List of file names.

  Returns:
    dict[str, list[str]]: Dictionary grouping filenames by device name.
  """
  grouped_files = defaultdict(list)
  for file in files:
    device_name = get_device_name(file)
    grouped_files[device_name].append(file)
  return grouped_files


def delete_newer_files(files: list[str], current_month: int,
                       current_year: int) -> None:
  """Deletes newer files, keeping only the oldest file for the current month and year.

  Args:
    files: List of file names for a specific device.
    current_month: Current month.
    current_year: Current year.
  """
  files_to_keep = []
  for file in files:
    file_date_str = file.split("__")[0]
    file_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(file_date_str, "%d-%m-%Y").date()
    if file_date.month == current_month and file_date.year == current_year:
      files_to_keep.append(file)
  oldest_file = min(
      files_to_keep,
      default="",
      key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.split("__")[0], "%d-%m-%Y"))
  for file in files_to_keep:
    if file != oldest_file:
      os.remove(file)


def main() -> None:
  """Main function to execute the script."""
  print("Before:")
  _print_tar_files()
  today = datetime.date.today()
  current_month = today.month
  current_year = today.year
  files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith('.tar')]
  grouped_files = group_files_by_device(files)
  for device_files in grouped_files.values():
    delete_newer_files(device_files, current_month, current_year)
  print("After:")
  _print_tar_files()


def _print_tar_files() -> None:
  tar_files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith('.tar')]
  print('\n'.join(sorted(tar_files)))


def _create_files_for_demonstration_purposes() -> None:
  file_names = [
      "02-10-2023__Device1.tar", "03-10-2023__Device2.tar",
      "01-11-2023__Device1.tar", "03-11-2023__Device2.tar",
      "04-11-2023__Device1.tar", "06-11-2023__Device2.tar",
      "11-11-2023__Device2.tar"
  ]
  for file_name in file_names:
    subprocess.run(['touch', file_name])


if __name__ == "__main__":
  _create_files_for_demonstration_purposes()
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
Before:
01-11-2023__Device1.tar
02-10-2023__Device1.tar
03-10-2023__Device2.tar
03-11-2023__Device2.tar
04-11-2023__Device1.tar
06-11-2023__Device2.tar
11-11-2023__Device2.tar
After:
01-11-2023__Device1.tar
02-10-2023__Device1.tar
03-10-2023__Device2.tar
03-11-2023__Device2.tar
```

Comment: It works as it should and the result is as expected. I will take a look at each step first (will take sime time ;) ). Thanks Sash!